# Determining if a URL contains a certain hostname

Tags: php, preg-match

I need to make a regular expression for php preg_match that does the following matching.

This is the function

```
function isValidURL($url,$searchfor){
    return preg_match("/\b.$searchfor \b/i", $url);
}
```

I need to find the somedomain.com in the following
Possible Strings entering the function

```
http://www.somedomain.com
http://somedomain.com
http://www.somedomain.com/anything
http://somedomain.com/anything
http://anything/somedomain.com
```

So I need a regular expression that does this

```
http://www.somedomain.com           Will Match
http://somedomain.com               Will Match
http://www.somedomain.com/anything  Will Match
http://somedomain.com/anything      Will Match
```

but

```
http://anything/somedomain.com      Will NOT match
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this requires is a placeholder for the URL beginning. Excluding slashes with a negated character class `[^/]` might already be sufficient:

```
function isValidURL($url,$searchfor){
    return preg_match("~http://[^/\s]*\.$searchfor(/|$|\s)~i", $url);
}
```

Note that this fails some edge cases, like `user:pw@` pairs. And no idea if your `$searchfor` was supposed to contain the TLD already. Also don't forget to `preg_quote` it.

Answer (score 3):

What about using [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url)?

```
if( strpos(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST), 'somedomain.com') !== false )
{
  // hostname contains 'somedomain.com'.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
$url = "http://komunitasweb.com/";
if (preg_match('/^(http|https|ftp)://([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*(?:.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+):?   (d+)?/?/i', $url)) {
    echo "Your url is ok.";
} else {
    echo "Wrong url.";
}
```

Copied from a google searh on "php url regular expression".  Check google out, awesome tool. :-)

Comment: Not exactly an answer to his question (he only allows *one particular* domain I believe!) but this should get him started.

Comment: Found it somewhere on the Google isn't proper attribution. And it might not be what OP asked for (even vague as the question is). If it's from catswhocode, then no, it won't even run without syntax error.

Comment: hmm this one seems to check if it is a true url. 
what i am trying to do is to check if a url in a page is an internal link or an external link. For example if i am searching a page with the domain www.thedomain.com
the external links should start like href="http://www.anotherdomain.gr/thererest". but i cant asume that an external link is the one that starts with http:// because someone can put http://www.mydomain.com/images/image.jpg instead of images/image.jpg. so if i find mydomain.com in the string http://www.mydomain.com/images/image.jpg its still an internal link.